# FastAPI + MongoDB: bson.errors.InvalidId: '2021-01-01_2021-12-31' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, fastapi

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the items from collection, that are inserted in some given time scope (e.g. 2021-01-01 - 2021-12-31).

Model.py:

```
    customer: str = Field(...)
    request_num: int = Field(...)
    name: str = Field(...)
    dates: date
    products_ids: list = Field()
    deadline: date
    finished: date
    notes: str = Field(...)

    class Config(BaseConfig):
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda dt: dt.isoformat()
        }
```

database.py

```
    requests = []
    async for request in range((request_collection.find({"dates": date_from })),\
                               (request_collection.find({"dates": date_to }))):
        requests.append(request_helper(request))
    return requests
```

Route.py

```
@router.get("/{date_from}_{date_to}")
async def get_request_year(date_from, date_to):
    request = await retrive_year_requests(date_from, date_to)
    if request:
        return request
    return ErrorRequestModel("An error occurred.", 404, "request doesn't exist.")
```

After when I put the route with time scope (http://localhost:8000/request/2021-01-01_2021-12-31) I receive the 500 Internal Server Error, and from the API site:
`bson.errors.InvalidId: '2021-01-01_2021-12-31' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string` Error.
I would be very grateful for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.col.aggregate([{'$and': [{"submit_date": {"$lt": datetime.datetime(year=2000, month=1, day=1)}},
                                            {"submit_date": {"$gte": datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=12, day=20)}}]}])
```

you can use like this to get date between 2000 and 2021